# SAS - looping through a source table and inserting into destination tables

Tags: sas

I was wondering if anyone can help with a sas problem i have.

I have to go over 10000 rows in an existing source table and insert the source table values into multiple destination tables.  I have to do the inserts one row at at time from the source table and also make sure to insert the primary key from the parent table(during insert) into the child tables (during insert)

I am using SAS API (SAS EG)

Here is what the **source table** looks like (please note this is another table not a data proc), the name of this table is countrycodelist which has the following columns for example:

```
Txn_id  statuscode  Typecode  classcode  identifier 

001          2          cnt      p1         13485
002          2          na       n1         13444
003          4          cnt      n1         12888
```

Right now i have the following code for the destination table:
NOTE: destination tables are already created and i have to just insert into them (tableA/tableB)

```
PROC SQL;
Insert into tableA (TXNID, STATUSCODE,CREATET,LASTUPDATET)
Select TXN_ID,STATUSCODE, datetime(), datetime()
From CountryCodeList
;
```

Quit;

After the above code has run status code is inserted into the table sim.tableA but this table has a key (pk) that is autoincrement. I need to use this key to insert into the child table so that a proper connection is made from the parent table to the child table below.

```
PROC SQL;
Insert into tableB (tableAID,TypeCode,ClassCode,DisplayID,)
Select 1101,TypeCode,ClassCode,Identifier
From CountryCodelist;
QUIT;
```

I manually inserted the last PK# from the tableA (1101) this works for small table inserts, but in large scale inserts i would need to grab the last PK from tableA and insert into tableB. SQL has functions such as scope_identity() or usage of @@IDENTITY to get last inserted key but these don't work in SAS or maybe I am going about it the wrong way.

Also i need to process these inserts one row at a time from the source table (CountryCodelist). This countrycodelist table can be updated over time and could grow past 10k records

Comment: You don't provide enough detail to answer this, I don't really think.  How are you identifying the destination tables - are they contingent on the data, or insert into all destination tables every time, or something else?  Why do you say you need to insert one by one?  What kind of table is this?

Comment: Is this really just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894396/passing-a-identity-key-from-one-table-insert-to-another-table-insert-in-sas ?

Comment: you are right joe, i have merged the two and deleted the old one. Sorry for the confusion/oversight

Comment: Still not getting it.  Maybe show an example of what your code would look like if you had only 3 records in your source data.

Comment: The edits improved it.  But still not getting the full picture.  When you run the insert into tableA, it will insert 3 records.  If  TableA already had 1100 records, the new records would be 1101, 1102, 1103.  So now you want to insert these same 3 records into tableB, right?  Are there also 1100 records in tableB before the insert?  Do you want these records to be pk=1101, 1102, 1103 in tableB as well?  Or do you want all three records to be inserted into tableB with pk=1101.

Comment: Correct Quentin, the new records into table A will be 1101, 1102 and 1103. I am inserting only statuscode and txnid in tableA, typecode/classcode/identifier are to be inserted into tableB. Dont ask me why the system was designed like this but it is and i have to deal with this structure. So when i insert into table b i have to take the pk from tableA and put it into tableB so 1101, 1102 and 1103 are in tableB as well not all three records to be inserted into tableB as 1101. I hope this clears things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll take a shot. Would following process work for what you want?  If it does, we can turn it into code:

1. Identify the maximum key in TableA
2. Insert one record from CountryCodeList into Table A.
3. Assign a talbeAID value to that record of maxKey+1.
4. Insert that record (with maxKey+1 as tableAID now in it) into Table B
5. Goto 1

Still don't understand a lot.  For example, why one record at a time?  And if table A and table B will always have the same number of records, than this should be much easier.  But does a process like that make sense for what you want?

Comment: yup you got it, well I am new to the coding world so if you think a simultaneous dump of all 10k records can work by picking up the right id from tableA and associating it to tableb without any mix ups that would be great. Table A and Table B will always have the same # of records because they are sourcing the primary information from one source table and just breaking up the source information into two destination tables

Comment: hey, i have given your post a green check since this is what i am hoping to learn how to do.